# custom path for prometheus actuator

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am currently trying to migrate our prometheus lib to spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE.
We use a custom path for prometheus and so far we use a work around to ensure this. As there is the possibility for a custom path for the info- and health-endpoint, uses `management.endpoint.<health/info>.path`. 
I tried to specify `management.endpoint.prometheus.path`, but it was still just accessible under `/actuator/prometheus`.

How can I use a custom path or prometheus?

We enable prometheus using the following libs (snippet of our build.gradle)

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.0.3.RELEASE"
compile "io.micrometer:micrometer-core:2.0.5"
compile "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:2.0.5"
```

we also use the import of the class `PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration`

Your help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-custom-mapping):

> By default, endpoints are exposed over HTTP under the /actuator path by using the ID of the endpoint. For example, the beans endpoint is exposed under /actuator/beans. If you want to map endpoints to a different path, you can use the management.endpoints.web.path-mapping property. Also, if you want change the base path, you can use management.endpoints.web.base-path.
>
> The following example remaps /actuator/health to /healthcheck:
>
> #### application.properties:
>
> ```
> management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
> management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck
> ```

So, to remap the prometheus endpoint to a different path beneath `/actuator` you can use the following property:

```
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.prometheus=whatever-you-want
```

The above will make the Prometheus endpoint available at `/actuator/whatever-you-want`

If you want the Prometheus endpoint to be available at the root, you'll have to move all the endpoints there and remap it:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.prometheus=whatever-you-want
```

The above will make the Prometheus endpoint available at `/whatever-you-want` but with the side-effect of also moving any other enabled endpoints up to `/` rather than being beneath `/actuator`.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add that changing `management.endpoints.web.base-path` to root has one side-effect -- you lose ability to query actuator 'discovery page' `/actuator` with links to all the endpoints.

> When the management context path is set to /, the discovery page is disabled to prevent the possibility of a clash with other mappings.

from [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.hypermedia)