# Changing spring boot actuator health end point to a custom end point

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible to change the spring boot actuator health end point to a custom end point? Something like the below.

http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

to

http://localhost:8080/myapp/apphealth

Wanted only the name change but not the response of the actuator/health. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom path for prometheus actuator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195237/custom-path-for-prometheus-actuator)

Answer (score 30):

**Yes**, it is possible.

How to customize the paths to your actuator endpoints is defined in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path) section of the documentation.

The documentation states:

> If you want to map endpoints to a different path, you can use the
> management.endpoints.web.path-mapping property.
>
> The following example remaps /actuator/health to /healthcheck:
>
> application.properties.
>
> management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
>
> management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck

So, in your case you want:

```
-- application.properties --
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/myapp
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=apphealth
```

Answer (score 20):

The answers given here, have already provided the solution for this question. But, I was struggling in customising the actuator health endpoint for different purposes, and I would like to share my findings to help someone else as well. All examples below are for `Spring Boot 2.x`.

The default actuator health endpoint would be http://localhost:8080/actuator/health.

---

**Option 1: Change `/actuator/health` to be a Custom Path like `/actuator/test`**

Add the following to your `application.properties` file

```
-- application.properties --
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=test
```

the path would be: http://localhost:8080/actuator/test

---

**Option 2: Change `/actuator/health` to be a Custom Path like `/myapp/test`**

Add the following to your `application.properties` file

```
-- application.properties --
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/myapp
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=test
```

the path would be: http://localhost:8080/myapp/test

---

**Option 3: Change `/actuator/health` to be a Custom Path like `/health`**

Add the following to your `application.properties` file

```
-- application.properties --
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

the path would be: http://localhost:8080/health

---

**Option 4: Change `/actuator/health` to be a Custom Path like `/test`**

Add the following to your `application.properties` file

```
-- application.properties --
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=test
```

the path would be: http://localhost:8080/test

---

**Option 5: Change Port from `8080` to custom port like `8081`**

Add the following to your `application.properties` file. The main application will run on Port `8080`.

```
-- application.properties --
management.server.port=8081
```

the path would be: http://localhost:8081/actuator/health

Comment: Is it possible to retain /actuator as the default path for all endpoints *except* health? I'd like to be able to provide secure access to just one client at /actuator/*, but pull up "health" to be just "/health" and accessible to all. Obviously, it's possible with a lot of manual configuration steps, but is there an easy way?

Comment: @JoshGough Did you manage to keep /actuator as the default path?