# Custom path for "/actuator/health/liveness" and "/actuator/health/readiness" endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in my Java Spring Boot application and I would like to customize some default endpoint paths provided by Actuator. For instance, I've been able to map "`/actuator/prometheus`" to "`/metrics`" by adding the following lines to the `application.properties` file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=prometheus
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.prometheus=metrics
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to map "`/actuator/health/liveness`" to "`/healthz`" and "`/actuator/health/readiness`" to "`/readyz`".

I tried to add the following lines to the `application.properties` file but it doesn't work:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health.liveness=healthz
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health.readiness=readyz
```

At the moment I'm thinking of not using Actuator in order to achieve those customizations. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing spring boot actuator health end point to a custom end point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654763/changing-spring-boot-actuator-health-end-point-to-a-custom-end-point)

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is slightly different: I would like to use "`/healthz`" instead of "`/actuator/health/liveness`" and I haven't find a way to do it by setting `management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health` property