# Prometheus Scrape Configuration for Springboot and non-Springboot Rest API's

Tags: prometheus

I have springboot and non-springboot (Eclipse Microprofile) Rest APIs running in openshift . Both are have service endpoint port 9443

SpringBoot metrics path - /actuator/prometheus
Eclipse Microprofile metrics path /metrics

Eclipse Microprofile scrape config

```
    - job_name: 'microprofile-metric'
      scrape_interval: 1m
      metrics_path: /metrics
      scheme: https
      bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
```

Springboot scrape config

```
    - job_name: 'springboot-metric'
      scrape_interval: 1m
      metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
      scheme: https
      bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
```

As the MP metrics are not available in springboot apps, seeing WARN of NOT Found endpoint (/metircs) in the application logs and same is the case with microprofile apps - /actuator/prometheus endpoint not found.

How can I can configure proemtheus scraping ?

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on stackoverflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654763/changing-spring-boot-actuator-health-end-point-to-a-custom-end-point#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20it%20is%20possible.,you%20can%20use%20the%20management.) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195237/custom-path-for-prometheus-actuator) and learned something new, We can set custom path for springboot actuators.

set these up

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.prometheus=metrics
```

and viola, issue resolved.

A huge shoutout to Stackovrlfow maintainers, contributors and of course the users, all of you made my day.